# How to compare two table columns when data is filled with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Sample table :**

```
Declare @t table (Name Varchar(20))
Insert into @t (name)values ('Raj')
Insert into @t (name)values ('bhoj')
Insert into @t (name)values ('Chess')
Insert into @t (name)values ('Win')


Declare @tt table (Name Varchar(20))
Insert into @tt (name)values ('E_Raj')
Insert into @tt (name)values ('H/bhoj')
Insert into @tt (name)values ('Chs')
Insert into @tt (name)values ('Winner game')
```

Simple Join :

```
select T.Name,TT.Name from @t T
    Inner Join @tt TT
    On T.Name = TT.Name
```

But I have tried with different conditions 
Ex:

```
REPLACE([t].[Name],'E_','')
```

and this condition

```
[t].[Name]  like '%' + [tt].[Name]   + '%'
```

How can I get the both tables with satisfying all conditions.

**Output :**

```
T.Name  TT.Name 
Raj      Raj
bhoj     bhoj     
Chess    Chs
Win      Winner game
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this also works with chess ([SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))
try this

```
select T.Name,TT.Name from @t T
    Inner Join @tt TT
    On T.Name like  '%' + TT.Name + '%' OR TT.Name like  '%' + T.Name + '%' 
    or SOUNDEX(TT.Name) = soundex(T.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want:

```
select T.Name, TT.Name
from @t T Inner Join
     @tt TT
     on TT.Name like '%' + T.Name + '%' or
        T.Name like '%' + TT.Name + '%';
```

This does not match `Chess` and `Chs`.  None of your conditions actually match them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it is possible to cover "Chess" case with missing letter inside, however other ones are covered by following query:

```
select T.Name,TT.Name from @t T
    Inner Join @tt TT
    On T.Name like  '%' + TT.Name + '%' OR TT.Name like  '%' + T.Name + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY**, I think `CHARINDEX` will be useful in this scenario, though it will not match `Chess` and `Chs`

```
SELECT T.Name,TT.Name 
FROM @t T
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TT.Name FROM @tt TT) tt
WHERE CHARINDEX(t.Name, tt.Name, 0) > 0
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Name    Name
Raj     E_Raj
bhoj    H/bhoj
Win     Winner game
```